# PHP header redirect doesn't work in IE 8

Tags: php, redirect, internet-explorer-8, header

I'm using in redirecting by header(Location : 'http://..' ) command in PHP.
It's working in FireFox and Chrome but not in IE 8.
I'm getting the error:
"Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage"
and it's though the page is indeed existed.

What may be the reason for it?

The redirect function:

```
function redirect($url, $statusCode = 303) {
    header('Location: ' . $url, true, $statusCode);
    die();
}
```

The call:

```
redirect("/page.php");
```

Thanks,
Nimrod.

Comment: Show the code and if possible, the URL

Comment: Can you reproduce this with a small enough piece of code to post and show us?

Comment: Try header('Location: ' . url); exit;

Comment: Don't put quotes around the URL.

Answer (score 2):

The PHP manual says:

> HTTP/1.1 requires an absolute URI as argument to » Location: including the scheme, hostname and absolute path, but some clients accept relative URIs. You can usually use $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] and dirname() to make an absolute URI from a relative one yourself:

```
<?php
/* Redirect to a different page in the current directory that was requested */
$host  = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$uri   = rtrim(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), '/\\');
$extra = 'mypage.php';
header("Location: http://$host$uri/$extra");
exit;
?>
```

I think IE8 is one of those browsers...

Comment: Did you try to access the page directly in IE8? Which url is displayed in the address bar after PHP redirects you?

Comment: Yes, I tried it.
The main page is shown in the URL (The page which is calling to the redirect action).
It seems that there is any problem with IE8 and header() command.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you also need to set the HTTP status code to one of 3xx

Comment: `header("location:`  does that automatically

Comment: @nimi - you right. Thinking of a different language than PHP.